# How do i get Keyword mapping working in NEST?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm on NEST v6.3.1, ElasticSearch v6.4.2

I can't get my field to be indexed as a keyword.

I've tried both attributes:

```
[Keyword]
public string Suburb { get; set; }
```

and fluent:

```
client.CreateIndex(indexName, i => i
                .Mappings(ms => ms
                    .Map<Listing>(m => m
                        .Properties(ps => ps
                            .Keyword(k => k
                                .Name(n => n.Suburb)))
                        .AutoMap())
                    .Map<Agent>(m => m
                        .AutoMap())
                    .Map<BuildingDetails>(m => m
                        .AutoMap())
                    .Map<LandDetails>(m => m
                        .AutoMap())
                )
            );
```

Both result in the same thing:

```
{
  "listings": {
    "mappings": {
      "listing": {
        "properties": {          
          "suburb": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

e.g doesn't match what i'm seeing here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/attribute-mapping.html

Same thing happens when i try and use `[GeoPoint]`. Should be type geopoint, but it's mapped to floats:

```
"latLong": {
            "properties": {
              "lat": {
                "type": "float"
              },
              "lon": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          }
```

So i'm missing something, just not sure what.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index likely already exists, and a field mapping cannot be updated. Check `.IsValid` on the response from the create index call, and if invalid, take a look at the error and reason. You likely need to delete the index and create again.

Also note that multiple type mappings in one index is not allowed in Elasticsearch 6.x, and will fail. Either create separate indices for different types, or, if the types have the same field structure *and* you wish to index/analyze them in the same way, you may consider introducing an additional discriminator field.

Comment: Yeah, i figured it out (then came here to close the q :) ) It was because i had multiple mappings, like you've said. They're just nested members of the root `Listing`, so they didn't need seperate AutoMap calls. Thanks :)